# Getting error 400 on ajax request on Wordpress custom theme

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm writing a Wordpress custom theme and in one of the pages, I have a form with two selects and a submit button. Basically the user can select two cities and check if there's a route between them.
I am using an Advanced Custom Fields Relationship field to link the cities (city is a post type).
The problem is I'm always getting a 400 error and I cannot figure what is the problem.

I have checked different solutions found here but none of them seems to work for me.

admin-ajax.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_check_route', 'check_route');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_route', 'check_route');

function check_route() {
    $id_cidade_origem = intval($_REQUEST['cidade_origem']);
    $id_cidade_destino = intval($_REQUEST['cidade_destino']);

    $cidades_atendidas = get_field('regioes_atendidas', $id_cidade_origem);

    $tem_relacao = False;
    foreach ($cidades_atendidas as $cidade) {
        if($cidade->ID == $id_cidade_destino){
            $tem_relacao = True;
            break;
        }
    }
    $data = array(
        'success' => true,
        'tem_relacao' => true
    );
    wp_send_json_success($data);
    $data = array(
        'success' => false
    );
    wp_send_json_error($error_data);
}
```

scripts.js:

```
jQuery("#regioes-botao").click(function (){
        console.log("Clicou!");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: 'check_route',
                cidade_origem: jQuery('#select-from').find(":selected").val(),
                cidade_destino: jQuery('#select-to').find(":selected").val(),
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (output) {
               console.log('sucesso!')
               console.log(output);
               var resposta = output.tem_relacao;
               if(resposta == true){
                    jQuery('#resposta span').text("Nós fazemos esta rota, entre em contato.")
               }else{
                    jQuery('#resposta span').text("No momento não fazemos esta rota, mas já estamos trabalhando para que seja possível em breve.")
               }
            },
            error: function(output){
                console.log(output)
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: try changing the code as follow: `data: {
                'action': 'check_route',
                'cidade_origem': jQuery('#select-from').find(":selected").val(),
                'cidade_destino': jQuery('#select-to').find(":selected").val(),
            },
            contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: Hi @FahamShaikh, thanks for your response. Unfortunately it didn't work, do you have another idea?

Comment: Well the only thing that I can think of is removing the `contentType` as sometimes it can cause an error. And serializing your data as `data: JSON.stringify({ 'action': 'check_route', 'cidade_origem': jQuery('#select-from').find(":selected").val(), 'cidade_destino': jQuery('#select-to').find(":selected").val(), }),`

Comment: @FahamShaikh It didn't work either :(

Comment: Okay one thing that I am sure is going to work, I am adding that in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 400 means that your originating request is not understandable for the server. Try the below written code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajax_object.ajax_url, //Used wp_localize_script to pass ajax url to wordpress. Example is at https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        'action': 'check_route', 
        'cidade_origem': jQuery('#select-from').find(":selected").val(),
        'cidade_destino': jQuery('#select-to').find(":selected").val(), 
    },
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.fail(function() {
})
.always(function() {
});
```

Do note that I have only defined request type, url to call and the data to send. I am pretty sure that this should work as I am using this in many of my projects.

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work for me though. But I got it working, just made a "template" with the code and and made a get request to that page instead of the /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: @Luc `url: ajax_object.ajax_url,` points to  ajax url passed to the file by localizing the parameters to the script file. If you are doing this in template, use **POST** instead of **GET** and make sure to properly sanitize input and output.